# What is the method for uninstalling a previous version in different directory in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I'm tweaking an NSIS installer to better handle non-default install directories and I've hit a problem.

My installer checks for an existing install and calls the existing uninstaller if there is one via:

```
'"$OLD_INSTDIR\uninstall.exe" /S _?=$OLD_INSTDIR'
```

Where $OLD_INSTDIR is a Var I've created an populated from a registry entry. This works fine, but I've been testing the scenario where someone changes the install directory from where the existing install is and noticed that the uninstaller executable and the old install directory aren't deleted.

After a bit of digging, I understand that the _?=$OLD_INSTDIR parameter causes the installer to run where it is rather than getting copied to a temp directory. This would explain why the delete doesn't occur.

I've tried explicitly deleting the uninstaller and directory after the existing version is uninstalled, but this doesn't work for me either.

```
ExecWait '$UNINSTALL_OLD_VERSION'
Delete $OLD_INSTDIR/uninstall.exe
RmDir $OLD_INSTDIR
```

Any ideas on what I should be doing? Apologies if this is something trivial, but my familiarity with NSIS is pretty much limited to building the installer from examples and then never touching it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
ExecWait '"$OLD_INSTDIR\uninstall.exe" /S _?=$OLD_INSTDIR'
Delete "$OLD_INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
RmDir "$OLD_INSTDIR"
```

_?= stops the usual copy to %temp% behavior, but also prevents the uninstaller from deleting itself, so you need to first run with the _? parameter and then delete the uninstaller

Comment: That is what I'm doing and it isn't working. The '$UNINSTALL_OLD_VERSION' is just the uninstaller line above in a variable.

Comment: But the uninstaller will do its work? If just the delete is failing, I suggest that you try Sysinternal's Process Monitor...

Comment: As it says in http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.1 : Warning: using RMDir /r $INSTDIR in the uninstaller is not safe. Though unlikely, the user might have installed to Program Files and this command will wipe out the entire Program Files folder, including other programs that has nothing to do with the uninstaller. The user can also put other files but the program's files and would expect them to get deleted with the program. Solutions are available for uninstalling only files which were installed by the installer here: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Uninstall_only_installed_files

Comment: @Anders - my mistake - after hours of research and experimenting, I was seeing /r everywhere. :-( Should I delete my comment?